# How can I convert these commands to work in Ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, windows, virtualbox, macosx

I was just following [a guide for Virtual Box.](http://www.insanelymac.com/forum/topic/309654-run-vanilla-os-x-el-capitan-yosemite-or-mavericks-in-virtualbox-5010-on-a-windows-host/) I tested the guide in Windows, since that's what it was written for. But now I want to use the same guide for Ubuntu.

VB is the same on both platforms, so that should be fine. But a part of the guide requires me to use the Windows command prompt.

These are the commands:

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\"
VBoxManage setextradata "El_Capitan" "VBoxInternal/Devices/efi/0/Config/DmiSystemProduct" "iMac11,3"
VBoxManage setextradata "El_Capitan" "VBoxInternal/Devices/efi/0/Config/DmiSystemVersion" "1.0"
VBoxManage setextradata "El_Capitan" "VBoxInternal/Devices/efi/0/Config/DmiBoardProduct" "Mac-F2238BAE"
VBoxManage setextradata "El_Capitan" "VBoxInternal/Devices/smc/0/Config/DeviceKey" "ourhardworkbythesewordsguardedpleasedontsteal(c)AppleComputerInc"
VBoxManage setextradata "El_Capitan" "VBoxInternal/Devices/smc/0/Config/GetKeyFromRealSMC" 1
```

How can I change them to make them work under Ubuntu?

Comment: If virtualbox is installed, the command is just `vboxmanage` then the rest of the complete command.

Comment: @Terrance So, exactly the same commands? Only lower case on Ubuntu? (And obviously, the directory is different in the first command.)

Comment: `vboxmanage` should be in your path, so no need to go into another folder.  Yes, the rest of the command would be the same after that.

Comment: And yes, it is lowercase in Ubuntu.

Comment: @Terrance I see. I'm slightly confused. Maybe you could make an answer where you write the whole set of commands as they should be in Ubuntu?

Comment: OK, give me a bit here.  Gotta get in front of a computer.  :)

Comment: @Terrance Cool. I gotta go to bed, but will check on your answer tomorrow :)

Comment: Apparently, both `vboxmanage` and `VBoxManage` work, as they're both symlinks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

VirtualBox commands for Ubuntu are actually very similar to those from Windows or the Mac OS.  The good news is the `vboxmanage` command is installed into the path on Ubuntu systems so there is no need to go to specific folders to find it.

The commands would then be as follows from a terminal:

*Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open a terminal.  And these commands can be copied and pasted to the terminal.*

```
vboxmanage setextradata "El_Capitan" "VBoxInternal/Devices/efi/0/Config/DmiSystemProduct" "iMac11,3"
vboxmanage setextradata "El_Capitan" "VBoxInternal/Devices/efi/0/Config/DmiSystemVersion" "1.0"
vboxmanage setextradata "El_Capitan" "VBoxInternal/Devices/efi/0/Config/DmiBoardProduct" "Mac-F2238BAE"
vboxmanage setextradata "El_Capitan" "VBoxInternal/Devices/smc/0/Config/DeviceKey" "ourhardworkbythesewordsguardedpleasedontsteal(c)AppleComputerInc"
vboxmanage setextradata "El_Capitan" "VBoxInternal/Devices/smc/0/Config/GetKeyFromRealSMC" 1
```

As you will notice everything else after the `vboxmanage` command is identical as you are telling VirtualBox what extra data is going to be set to in the "El_Capitan" VM.

Hope this helps!